# App stuck at Core Data initialization. How to fix?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an `AppService.swift` with the following code.

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "AppName")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { storeDescription, error in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            self.log.error("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

func saveChannel(_ channel: Channel) {
    persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { context in
        let _channel = JSChannel(context: context)
        _channel.desc = channel.desc
        if let ret = try? context.save() {
            self.log.debug("ret: \(ret)")
        }
    }
}
```

I call `saveChannel` method and the app freezes. I added breakpoint and entered `p NSPersistentContainer(name: "AppName")` in the debugger and it does not completes the execution. The container name is same as the `xcdatamodelid`. I am using deployment target as `10.0` and Xcode `10.1`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by calling the persistentContainer in main queue.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { context in
    // ..
}
```